# How to calculate two circles bouncing off of each other?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, collision-detection

I want to animate two circles bouncing off of each other, but for that I need to know how to calculate the new exit angle. It doesn't have to be physically perfect (but can be, if that might be easier), I would just like to do a simple animation.

I have:

- Information about two circle's position, radius, speed and direction of movement (e.g. moving up would be 0° or 360°)
- The calculation to know when two circles are colliding

Now I "only" need to know what the new angle of the circles is, when two collide. Problem is, I am not a mathematician, so if you could give me a straight-up formula (if that is even possible), I would really appreciate it.

Here I have drawn an example of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: This is actually more of a physics problem than mathematics one, as what happens after collision should depend on the masses of the circles and whether it's an elastic/inelastic collision. Unless you having something else in mind.

Comment: No I actually do not care about masses. I just want a plain "stupid" collision, where the circles bounce off each other like they would all weight the same. It does not have to be physically correct, it's for a background animation on a webpage @ChristianBueno

Comment: Check this [Wiki page on elastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision)

Comment: @GeometryLover Thank you. I do understand that it might come off as me not doing my own research, but this looks really complicated to me. Could you maybe show me how to calculate that using my given information, or give me a link to a thorough explanation of the concept? With the Wikipedia article alone, I don't know where to start.

Comment: You want to read the section on 2D collision (with title: Two-dimensional collision with two moving objects), where it gives explicit formulas that involve the angles before and after the collision.  And then it lists a couple of equations described as being "angle-free representation".

Comment: for a perfect elastic collision, find the instant that the two circles collide; at that instant, draw the common tangent line to the two circles, which is the perpendicular bisector of the segment between the two circle centers.  Both circles bounce away as though that tangent line were a solid, fixed wall.  That's all you need

Comment: Thanks, I already got that that section will be the interesting one, but I can't figure out what to put into the formula. is phi the angle that I calculated on my image? How would I use the two different x and y velocities, to get back to my speed + angle representation? Btw, the second (angle-free) formula is for two objects going straight against each other, so basically not for my use-case, am I right? @GeometryLover

Comment: @WillJagy That's all I already have, if I understood that correctly. My question basically is, how would I calculate those new angles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quoting from this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision)

The bolded variables in the following equation are two-dimensional vectors.  These are: the position and velocity of particle 1 before collision: $\mathbf{x_1} $ and $\mathbf{v_1}$ and the position and velocity of particle 2 before the collision: $\mathbf{x_2} $ and $\mathbf{v_2}$.  In addition the vector $\mathbf{v'_1} $ is the velocity of the first particle immediately after collision while $\mathbf{v'_2}$ is the velocity vector of the second particle immediately after collision.

The equations are:

First define the unit normal vector $\mathbf{n} = \dfrac{\mathbf{x_1} - \mathbf{x_2} }{ \left| \mathbf{x_1} - \mathbf{x_2}   \right|}$

$\mathbf{v'_1} = \mathbf{v_1} - \dfrac{2 m_2}{m_1+m_2} (\mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2}) ) \mathbf{n} $

and

$\mathbf{v'_2} = \mathbf{v_2} - \dfrac{2 m_1}{m_1+m_2} (\mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{v_2}-\mathbf{v_1}) ) \mathbf{n} $

If we assume that $m_1 = m_2$ (equal masses) then the equations simplify to:

$\mathbf{v'_1} = \mathbf{v_1} - (\mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2}) ) \mathbf{n} $

and

$\mathbf{v'_2} = \mathbf{v_2} - (\mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{v_2}-\mathbf{v_1}) ) \mathbf{n} $

As an example, suppose both circles have the same radius and the same mass, and that the first circle is moving with its center position as function of time given by:

$\mathbf{x_1}(t) = (0, -10) + (1, 2) t $

it follows that

$\mathbf{v_1} = (1, 2)$

and suppose that the center of the second circle is
given by

$\mathbf{x_2} = (-10, 0) + (2, 1) t $

it follows that

$\mathbf{v_2} = (2, 1) $

We want to calculate the value of $t$ at which the two circles will collide.  Suppose the radius of each of the circles is $1$.  Then we want the distance between the centers to be $2$.

We have

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left| \mathbf{x_1}(t) - \mathbf{x_2}(t) \right| &=  \left|(10, -10) + t ( -1, 1 ) \right |\\
&= \sqrt{ 200 - 40 t + 2 t^2 } = 2
\end{split} \end{equation}$

Its solution is $t = 10 \pm \sqrt{2} $

So we'll select $t = 10 - \sqrt{2} $ (the first time after $t = 0$ )

So, at the collision , we have

$\mathbf{x_1} = (0, -10) + (10 - \sqrt{2}) (1, 2) = (10 -\sqrt{2} , 10 - 2 \sqrt{2} ) $

$\mathbf{x_2} = (-10, 0) + (10 - \sqrt{2}) (2, 1) = (10 - 2 \sqrt{2}, 10 - \sqrt{2} )$

Hence the normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ is given by

$\mathbf{n} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1, -1) $

Substituting all this into the equations, we obtain,

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{v'_1} &= (1, 2) - \dfrac{1}{2}( (1, -1)\cdot(1-2, 2 - 1) ) (1, -1) \\
&= (1, 2) + (1 , -1) = (2, 1) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Similarly, one can obtain that $\mathbf{v'_2} = (1, 2)$

Comment: Thanks a lot of man, that really helped me out! Got the algorithm down now, and it looks even better than I expected :)

Comment: Glad the solution helped.